# template<int N, int M> constructor instanciation

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, instantiation

Basically, I'm coding a Matrix class, but I want to instanciate it with `int[N][M]` variables.

I have this working (for 3, 3 matrix) :
matrix.h :

```cpp
class Matrix {
    private:
        unsigned cols, rows;
        int* data;
    public:
        Matrix(unsigned cols, unsigned row);
        Matrix(int mat[3][3]);
}
```

matrix.cpp :

```cpp
inline
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned cols, unsigned rows) : cols (cols), rows (rows) {
    if (rows == 0 || cols == 0) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Matrix constructor has 0 size");
    }
    data = new int[rows * cols];
}

Matrix::Matrix(int mat[3][3]) : Matrix(3, 3) {
    for(unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for(unsigned col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            (*this)(col, row) = mat[col][row];
        }
    }
}
```

I then tried to implement a template constructor :

```cpp
template<int N, int M>
Matrix(int[N][M]) : Matrix(N, M) {
    for(unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for(unsigned col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            (*this)(col, row) = mat[col][row];
        }
    }
}
```

which seems to compile, but when I execute a test function :

```cpp
void test() {
    int tab[3][3] = {
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9}
    };
    Matrix mat(tab);
}
```

I get this error :

```
matrix.cpp:10:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘Matrix::Matrix(int [3][3])’
     Matrix mat(tab);
```

even though I template it this way (in the .h file under the Matrix class) :

```cpp
template<> Matrix::Matrix<3, 3>(int[3][3]);
```

I could really use some help on this, and also on how to instanciate it with every combination of int from 0 to 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things...

First note that `Matrix(int[N][M])` is incomplete, and is missing an argument name. Also note that it's equivalent to `Matrix(int(*)[M])`.

Secondly, array dimensions are of type `size_t`, not `int`.

Thirdly, to pass an actual array and not a pointer, you need to take the array by reference.

Putting it all together your constructor should probably look something like

```
template<size_t N, size_t M>
Matrix(int const (&mat)[N][M]) : Matrix(N, M)
{
    for (size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
        for (size_t m = 0; m < m; ++m)
        {
            (*this)(n, m) = mat[n][m];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works really well ! Do you think I should use `size_t` instead of `unsigned` for my basic constructor as well `Matrix(unsigned cols, unsigned row)` ?

Comment: @startresse Yes, that's what `size_t` is for: To represent sizes. :) It also does makes it easier to read and understand your code, as seeing `size_t` implies the whole "this is a size", while `unsigned` could be "some arbitrary unsigned value".